# Is there a reason why Portal Title edit submissions stopped returning confirmation notices?

Tags: ingress

Since January 30th I have not received any confirmation emails for my title edit submissions. Usually within a few seconds of submitting an edit, Niantic sends out a confirmation notice. Note this is not the accept or reject which comes weeks or months later, this is just the submission received email.

I've checked my Ingress sync settings and they seem fine. The app is synchronizing other data constantly so that can't seem to be the issue. I've tried turning the sync setting off and on again, restarting the phone, etc. Nothing helps.

It seems other team-mates are still receiving submission confirmations. I suspect Niantic has done something specific to my account such as "mute" my submissions. In the past several weeks I submitted a lot of edit requests and I suspect the <strike>monkeys</strike> err...editors at Niantic had enough of me.

Is there any way to confirm this suspicion? Alternatively is there some other problem that could lead to this? And most importantly is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I received my latest data edit review on 2nd January, after 16 days in queue. I have a few more waiting later on. But I rarely get no answers from Nia for my edits. I still wait for an edit to be replied for over six months.

Comment: Hi, it's not about edit reviews but only the confirmation of the submission. The ones that are sent to you to confirm that they've received your submission. They are generally sent in a few seconds after a submission. I haven't received any since January 30.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Passed the edit period. I can confirm that latest confirmation mail I received is. On 23rd January. But not sure if I received all mails.

Comment: That's the weirdest thing! I've just checked my spam folder which was full with every kind of Niantic reports. I was so focused on just submission confirmations that I've totally forgot to realize that I wasn't even receiving the standard damage reports. Please put your comment as an answer so I can choose it as the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect it's more likely that the only suspicions raised are that of your spam filters, A whole bunch of nearly identical messages coming though in a short amount of time from an address you never send anything to might have set off some alarm at your email host. I suggest checking your spam folder and adding Niantic's confirmation addresses to your contacts. If you find the messages there you can also select them and mark them as "not spam" to retrain the filter a little bit.