# Changing the name of a Portal

Tags: ingress

I tried to change the name of a Portal. The business which used to be where that location is at is no longer in business and a new business is there. So, I wanted to update the picture and name. When I touched the picture in the game, to 'edit' it provided me with update capabilities but then that's where it became a problem. I tried to use the 'Google' update capability - and that wouldn't refresh the information. Why not? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I think we crashed the Pokemon Go servers so much that the Ingress servers broke too.

Comment: @Studoku I think they broke their own servers by releasing Pokemon Go to 26 additional countries

Comment: Possible related answer: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/203995/is-there-a-reason-why-portal-title-edit-submissions-stopped-returning-confirmati

Answer (score 4):

The Portal name and photo editing functionality doesn't change the Portal name and photo immediately. Your request will be examined by Niantic and if it's a proper request will be implemented. Nowadays this process takes a few months.

A confirmation email will be sent in just a few seconds after pressing the "Send" button on the edit window. If you're not receiving this confirmation there is a [possibility that it is being tagged as spam by your email service provider because you're sending too much requests and receiving too much confirmation emails](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/203995/82644).

Yes, Niantic doesn't provide you with information that the Portal already has a waiting request by you or other agents. You can only find it out by looking at your own request confirmation emails or when you get an answer (positive or negative) from Niantic.

Comment: What's too bad about this - is when the update request is sent to them, there's no 'thank you your change request has been submitted' response from the game. Also, for those that come back to it - there's no place where it says that there's a change pending. So, someone next week could possibly go in and request the exact same change as well.

Answer (score 0):

I get a lot more portal photo review than portal name review accepted though. Even if the requested change is legitimate, it doesn't mean Niantic is going to accept it.

Be patient and don't expect any fast answers from Niantic.

Portal reviews takes usually 1 month+ before it's accepted or declined.